# Map generic array to array of TypeScript classes

Tags: typescript, axios, mapping

I have a `typescript` class:

```
export class Vehicle {
  constructor(
    id: string,
    makeId: string,
    makeName: string,
    modelName: string,
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.makeId = makeId;
    this.makeName = makeName;
    this.modelName = modelName;
  }

  public id: string;
  public makeId: string;
  public makeName: string;
  public modelName: string;
}
```

Next, I have an `axios` post:

```
var results = await axios({
  method: "post",
  url: `${api}/api/vehicles`,
  responseType: "json",
  data: {
    searchTerm: searchTerm
  }
});
```

This post returns the following `json`:

```
results: {
    data: {
        suggestions: [
            {
                data: {
                    id: "93dbae75-cf32-11e9-904a-88d7f67d5c52",
                    makeId: "8641d37e-cf1e-11e9-904a-88d7f67d5c52",
                    makeName: "Audi",
                    modelName: "TT RS Coupe"
                },
                value: "(2012) Audi - TT RS Coupe"
            },
            {
                data: {
                    id: "93dcc3f4-cf32-11e9-904a-88d7f67d5c52",
                    makeId: "8641d37e-cf1e-11e9-904a-88d7f67d5c52",
                    makeName: "Audi",
                    modelName: "TT RS Coupe"
                },
                value: "(2013) Audi - TT RS Coupe"
            },
            {
                data: {
                    id: "72c4afcb-cf32-11e9-904a-88d7f67d5c52",
                    makeId: "862fba2f-cf1e-11e9-904a-88d7f67d5c52",
                    makeName: "Acura",
                    modelName: "RSX"
                },
                value: "(2003) Acura - RSX"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

How do i map this `json` resultset into an array of my typescript class? I've tried the following:

```
for(let result in results.data.suggestions) {
  vehicles.push(result.data:Vehicle);
}
```

It is, however, picking up the `result` in `let result` as a string. If I `console.log` the result, I get the array index.

Comment: *"This post returns the following json"* Hopefully not, as that's not [JSON](https://json.org).

Comment: axios returns `Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>` by default, so you can just type your `var results`  as `var result: AxiosResonse<InterfaceForYourData>` and get all typings for free. No need to waste resources with a pointless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem is that you're using `for-in` to loop through the array entries, and that's not what `for-in` does. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) for details, but you probably want `for-of`. Also, the colon doesn't do [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), for that you use `<Vehicle>result.data` or `result.data as Vehicle`.

```
for (const {data} of results.data.suggestions) {
  vehicles.push(data as Vehicle); // Or you may need `data as unknown as Vehicle`
}
```

The separate problem is that if you do what you've described, the objects won't be instances of `Vehicle`, although they will be compatible from a duck-typing perspective. That's fine **for now**, but if you ever give `Vehicle` methods, they won't have them.

You have a couple of options for addressing that:

1. Make `Vehicle` an `interface` rather than a `class`.
2. Make `Vehicle`'s constructor accept a `Vehicle`-like object rather than discrete parameters (perhaps via destructuring)
3. Overload the `Vehicle` constructor to accept a `Vehicle`-like object and populate the instance from it.

#1 is pretty obvious:

```
interface Vehicle {
  id: string;
  makeId: string;
  makeName: string;
  modelName: string;
}
```

Then your loop is as above:

```
for (const {data} of results.data.suggestions) {
  vehicles.push(data as Vehicle); // Or you may need `data as unknown as Vehicle`
}
```

#2 looks something like this:

```
interface VehicleLike {
  id: string;
  makeId: string;
  makeName: string;
  modelName: string;
}
export class Vehicle {
  // *** Note the { and } in the parameter list
  constructor({
    id,
    makeId,
    makeName,
    modelName
  }: VehicleLike) {
    this.id = id;
    this.makeId = makeId;
    this.makeName = makeName;
    this.modelName = modelName;
  }

  public id: string;
  public makeId: string;
  public makeName: string;
  public modelName: string;
}
```

Then

```
for (const {data} of results.data.suggestions) {
  vehicles.push(data as VehicleLike); // Or you may need `data as unknown as VehicleLike`
}
```

#3 looks something like this:

```
interface VehicleLike {
  id: string;
  makeId: string;
  makeName: string;
  modelName: string;
}
export class Vehicle {
  constructor(vehicle: VehicleLike);
  constructor(
    id: string,
    makeId: string,
    makeName: string,
    modelName: string,
  );
  constructor(
    x: string|VehicleLike,
    makeId?: string,
    makeName?: string,
    modelName?: string,
  ) {
    if (typeof x === "string") {
        this.id = x;
        this.makeId = makeId as string;
        this.makeName = makeName as string;
        this.modelName = modelName as string;
    } else {
        this.id = x.id;
        this.makeId = x.makeId;
        this.makeName = x.makeName;
        this.modelName = x.modelName;
    }
  }

  public id: string;
  public makeId: string;
  public makeName: string;
  public modelName: string;
}
```

Then (again)

```
for (const {data} of results.data.suggestions) {
  vehicles.push(data as VehicleLike); // Or you may need `data as unknown as VehicleLike`
}
```

---

Side note: **If** you don't change `Vehicle` per any of the above and you keep it the way you have it, and **if** you want to, this is functionally identical to your current `Vehicle`, just with a lot less repetition:

```
export class Vehicle {
  constructor(
   public id: string,
   public makeId: string,
   public makeName: string,
   public modelName: string,
  ) {
  }
}
```

It's a convenience feature TypeScript provides.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I just tried using the `for of` loop before your edit and confirmed that the property values are accessible. I passed each property individually to the constructor. I thank you for providing some examples where the mapping within the constructor is better.